# Trying to pull commits over a period of time

Tags: api, github

i tried using gh api to retrieve commits with the following code

```
gh api repos/apache/airflow/commits
```

and it returns me only commits done for the past 3 days.

How do I retrieve for like maybe past 3 months?

I saw in the documentation that there is `since` and `until`. What should be the syntax?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, I have solved the issue using curl.

```
startdate='2022-02-26';
enddate='2022-08-27';
json_string=os.popen("curl -sS \"https://api.github.com/repos/apache/airflow/commits?since="+startdate+"T00:00:00Z&until="+enddate+"T23:59:59Z&per_page=100&page="+str(i)+"\"").read();
```